# (HTML) Can't use specific symbols

Tags: html, css

So, I'm starting to create a homepage for my homework, but I've stumbled upon a problem.

Basically, what I need my homepage to display is this kind of text: "Daudzspēlētāju tiešsaites lomu spēle (Massively Multiplayer Online Role-Playing Game), vai vienkārši MMORPG (angļu saīsinājums) ir spēles žanrs, kas sastāv no spēlēšanas internetā ar citiem spēlētājiem radītā vai īstā virtuālā pasaulē."

And this is what I'm getting: "DaudzspÄ“lÄ“tÄju tieÅ¡saites lomu spÄ“le (Massively Multiplayer Online Role-Playing Game), vai vienkÄrÅ¡i MMORPG (angÄ¼u saÄ«sinÄjums) ir spÄ“les Å¾anrs, kas sastÄv no spÄ“lÄ“Å¡anas internetÄ ar citiem spÄ“lÄ“tÄjiem radÄ«tÄ vai Ä«stÄ virtuÄlÄ pasaulÄ“."

This is what I currently have, and thank you for the help:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>

    <title> Sākums </title>

    <link rel="SHORTCUT ICON" href="./bildes/favicon.ico"/>

    <script src="./js/jquery2.1.4.min.js"></script>

      <script src="./js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

      <link href = "./css/bootstrap.min.css" rel = "stylesheet">

      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./stils.css">

</head>

<body>
     <div class = "navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top">
        <div class = "container">

            <li><a href = "#" class = "navbar-brand"> MMO/MMORPG </a></li>

            <button class = "navbar-toggle" data-toggle = "collapse" data-target = ".navHeaderCollapse">
            <span class = "icon-bar"></span>
            <span class = "icon-bar"></span>
            <span class = "icon-bar"></span>
            </button>

            <div class = "collapse navbar-collapse navHeaderCollapse">
                <ul class = "nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li class = "active">
                    <li><a href = "#">Sākums</a></li>
                    <li><a href = "./anketa.html">Anketa</a></li>
                    <li><a href = "./galerija.html">Galerija</a></li>
                    <li><a href = "./kontakti.html">Kontakti</a></li>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
     </div>

     <div class = "container">

        <div class = "jumbotron">

            <center> <h1> Kas ir MMO/MMORPG </h1>   

            <p>Daudzspēlētāju tiešsaites lomu spēle (Massively Multiplayer Online Role-Playing Game), vai vienkārši MMORPG (angļu saīsinājums) ir spēles žanrs, kas sastāv no spēlēšanas internetā ar citiem spēlētājiem radītā vai īstā virtuālā pasaulē. MMORPG ir izplatītākais MMO (massive multiplayer online) tipa spēļu paveids. Vēl eksistē MMOFPS (MMO first person shooter) un MMORTS (MMO real time strategy), bet šāda veida spēlēm ir lielākas prasības pret tīklu un servera resursiem, tāpēc tās ir mazāk izplatītas. Tās arī parādījās vēlāk. MMORPG no citiem tīkla RPG atšķiras ar to, ka serveri parasti uztur spēles izstrādātājkompānija, serverī vienlaikus var spēlēt ļoti liels spēlētāju skaits (vairāki tūkstoši) un par spēles spēlēšanu, ar retiem izņēmumiem, ir jāmaksā mēneša maksa. Tāpat kā citās RPG spēlēs, te viens no mērķiem ir līmeņa sišana. MMORPG ir iespējami uzdevumi (angļu: quest), taču tie nevar izmainīt spēles pasauli, atšķirībā no kvestiem parastajos RPG. </p>    

     </div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing a charset. Ideally this should be sent by the server in the Content-Type HTTP header, but you should also have it in the HTML itself:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
```

(to be added in your `<head>`)

Comment: Thank you a lot! I completely forgot about charset, and this fixed my problem!